# How can i get state of a checkbox whether is checked or no not in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

```
<input class="checkout-item" :value="cart_food.id" @change="sumOfProduct(cart_food.quantity,cart_food.variation.price)" name="cart_item[]"  v-model="checkbox" type="checkbox">

sumOfProduct(price,quantity) {
        this.productPrice = price;
        this.productQuantity = quantity;
        var total = (this.productPrice * this.productQuantity);
            this.totalPrice.push(total);
            this.totalPrice.pop(total);

            var sum = this.totalPrice.reduce(function(a, b)
            {
                return a + b;
            }, 0);

        console.log(sum);
        this.finalPrice = sum;
    },
```

In my sumOfProduct method i want to verify the checkbox whether it is checked or not. Any idea how can i achive this.

Comment: Hello @RIYAL and welcome to SO ! Check out my answer below and let me know if it helped you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put an v-model directive to your checkbox input, named "checkbox" . I assume you also included the same as reactive data prop like :

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checkbox : false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If that is the case , you can simple check `this.checkbox` for `true` or `false`.

```js
sumOfProduct(price,quantity) {
  console.log(this.checkbox);
}
```

If you also want to checkout the native "change" event inside your method, include `$event` as first argument when you call it.

```js
v-on:change="sumOfProduct($event, 2, 1.0)"

sumOfProduct(event, price, quantity) {
  console.log(event.target.checked);
  // false if unchecked, true if checked
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sky-5r7ii?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark